# How to solve these equations for x and y..

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

equations are

> $(x-y)(x+2y)(2x+y) = 20$

and

> $x^2+xy+y^2 = 7$

i want the METHOD not the solutions

Comment: My method was to put the equations in Excel and use the solver.  It's not an enlightening method, but it gives you an answer right away.  Ask your teacher if you can do this on a test :)

Answer (score 6):

**Method:** Express the equations in terms of $xy$, $x-y$ and then change variables.

Comment: This is a rabbit pulled out of a hat, how did you get to it?

Answer (score 5):

You are given:$$(x-y)(x+2y)(2x+y)=20\tag{1}$$$$x^2+xy+y^2=7\tag{2}$$Expand the last two terms in (1) to get:$$(x+2y)(2x+y)=2x^2+5xy+2y^2=2(x^2+xy+y^2)+3xy\tag{3}$$Substitute (2) into (3) to get:$$(x+2y)(2x+y)=2(7)+3xy=14+3xy\tag{4}$$Substitute (4) into (1) to get:$$(x-y)(14+3xy)=20\tag{5}$$Then use the hint given by @Leox, i.e. let:$$a=x-y\tag{6}$$$$b=xy\tag{7}$$To get:$$a(14+3b)=20$$$$\therefore 14+3b=\frac{20}{a}\tag{8}$$If it is integer solutions that you are looking for then $a$ must be evenly divisible into $20$ which means $a$ can only be from the set: $1,-1,2,-2,4,-4,5,-5,10,-10,20,-20$

Use each value of $a$ in (8) to see which ones give an integer solution for $b$.

Finally use (6) and (7) to then find $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Substitute $(6)$ and $(7)$ into $(2)$ to get $a^2+3b=7$.  Eliminate $b$ from this and $(8)$ to give a cubic in $a$.  The solutions are easy to find and it turns out that they are integers.

Comment: If he actually wants integer solutions (and he never mentioned it), then he could've just checked the various cases using the $(1)$ equation, e.g. one of the cases is $x-y=1, x+2y=4, 2x+y=5$.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion *for this problem* is to first complete the square in the second equation and then to change variables to get an ellipse with half axes parallel to the coordinate axes. Thus,
$$
(x+\tfrac{1}{2}y)^2+\tfrac{3}{4}y^2=7.
$$
Notice that $x+\tfrac{1}{2}y=\tfrac{1}{2}(2x+y)$ fits well with one factor in the first equation.

Thus, set $u=x+\tfrac{1}{2}y$ and $v=y$. The equations become (after a small simplification)
$$
u^2+\tfrac{3}{4}v^2=7,\quad\text{and}\quad 2u^3-\tfrac{9}{2}uv^2=20.
$$
Here, we could easily solve the first equation for $v^2$ and insert it into the second one. This will give a qubic equation in $u$, that can be solved rather easily. Inserting back into the first one and changing back to $x$ and $y$ will give a total of six pairs of solutions $(x,y)$ to the original equations.

Notice, that this is *not a general approach*, but a method to solve your system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

Equation 2 is the equation of an ellipse. Basically, any equation

\begin{eqnarray}
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + C = 0
\end{eqnarray}

can be translated, by a change of variable, into:

\begin{eqnarray}
\left(\frac{\tilde{x}}{a}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{\tilde{y}}{b}\right)^2 = 1
\end{eqnarray}

Leading to:
\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{x} & = & a\cos(\theta) \\
\tilde{y} & = & b\sin(\theta) \\
\tilde{y} & = & b\sqrt{1 - \frac{\tilde{x}^2}{a^2}}
\end{eqnarray}

Now, for the transformation from $(x, y)$ to $(\tilde{x}, \tilde{y})$, we need to find the rotation angle $\Theta$ and translation $(0,0) \mapsto (x_c, y_c)$ so that the ellipse is centered on $0$ and its minor and major axis are aligned with the axis of our base. Back to the generic equation of an ellipse:

\begin{eqnarray}
A & = & a^2 \sin(\Theta)^2 + b^2 \cos(\Theta)^2 \\
B & = & 2(b^2 - a^2)\sin(\Theta)\cos(\Theta) \\
C & = & a^2 \cos(\Theta)^2 + b^2 \sin(\Theta)^2 \\
D & = & -2Ax_c - By_c \\
E & = & -Bx_c - 2 Cy_c \\
F & = & Ax_c^2 + Bx_cy_c + Cy_c^2 - a^2b^2 \\
\end{eqnarray}

With $D$ and $E$, you can find $(x_c, y_c)$. Here, there are no term $D$ or $E$, because your ellipse is already centered on $0$. $A+C = a^2 + b^2$ and $F = a^2b^2$, so you deduce $a$ and $b$. Then $B= (b^2-a^2)sin(2\Theta)$, and you find $\theta$. So

\begin{eqnarray}
\tilde{x} & = & x\cos(\Theta) - y\sin(\theta) \\
\tilde{y} & = & x\sin(\Theta) + y\cos(\theta)
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

1073177
Use Sylvester's dialytic eliminant:
$\begin{vmatrix}
-2&-7x&3x^2&2x^3-20&0\\
0&-2&-7x&3x^2&2x^3-20\\
1&x&x^2-7&0&0\\
0&1&x&x^2-7&0\\
0&0&1&x&x^2-7\\
\end{vmatrix}$
$(=79x^6-1022x^4-80x^3+2891x^2+1120x-972)$
to get rid of the $y$s. Equate it to $0$, solve it for $x$, then substitute each value into one of the original equations (preferably the simpler one), then solve for the corresponding $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Do the operations to result to $$2x^3 + 3x^2y- 3xy^2 - 2y^3 - 20 = 0 \iff \\ 2(x^3 - y^3) +3xy(x-y) - 20 = 0 \iff \\ 2(x-y)(x^2 + xy + y^2) + 3xy(x-y) - 20 = 0 \iff \\ 14(x-y)+3xy(x-y) - 20 = 0$$

That simplifies the solution so keep substituting (2) into (1) to simplify the system

Answer (score 0):

Drawing the two associated curves, we see that there are $6$ simple solutions (the maximum according to Bezout theorem). Let $s=x+y,p=xy$. If $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(-y,-x)$ is also a solution. Thus the solutions in $p$ have multiplicity $2$ and $p$ is any root of a polynomial of degree $3$. In the same way, the solutions in $s$ are pairwise opposite.

We obtain $s^2=p+7$ and $(x-y)(2s^2+p)=2$ or $(x-y)(3p+14)=20$ that implies $(s^2-4p)(3p+14)^2=400$ or $(7-3p)(3p+14)^2=400$. The solutions are $p=-6,-3,2$ ; the corresponding values of $s$ are $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3$. The associated solutions in $(x,y)$ are $(-2,3),(-3,2)$ and $(3,-1),(1,-3)$ and $(-1,-2),(2,1)$.